# Testing android apps on Android Studio with physical device (Symphony w19)

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to debug an android application on a real phone (Symphony w19).

1. I enabled USB debugging on my Android Device.
2. I set true debug configuration in build grade and android main-feast file.
3. I set Deployment Target Selection Mode to Manual as USB device.

When I click on debug, I can't see my phonein the Android Device Chooser.
What can I do?

Comment: I guess your phone's driver is not installed on your computer.

Comment: What OS are you using (Win7/Win8,Mac,Linux)?

Comment: Driver already installed .

Comment: Maybe your device is one of those ones which requires to be set as **MTP device**?

Comment: No , i already  try many times set MTP , Storage's mode.But it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least I solved my problem by installing the universal windows adb driver.
See details here Click [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/configuring-your-windows-usb-android-debug-connection-for-the-intel-xdk#Debug_USB")!
This works with [reference links][blog] as well.